# Camera Nodelet using GPU memory?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, nodelet, image-transport, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

This is my first question, so apologize for any formatting mistakes.

I developed a simple driver in CPP for a IDS camera using IDS drivers and ROS nodelet.
The cameras publish using image transport.
However, I noticed that there is approximate 100 MB of GPU memory usage for every new camera publishing.
Since my system contains multiple deep neural networks nodes running I would like to have as much as possible of my GPU memory free.

Why is this happening? Anyone has any idea?

My guess is that image transport may be using the GPU for image compression, or other tasks. If so, there is a way to disable it and do everything in CPU?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351110/camera-nodelet-using-gpu-memory?/) by [gabrielPeixoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/54213/gabrielpeixoto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-01**:
Quick comment: it's very likely the IDS driver is using the GPU. I'm not aware of code in `image_transport` doing this (or at least not directly (ie: using any of the regular ways to do it, such as CUDA or OpenCL)). But as `image_transport` is plugin based, you could of course have plugins installed which do. We cannot know. That would be something for you to check.

**Comment by [gabrielPeixoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/54213/gabrielpeixoto/) on 2020-05-01**:
Indeed, to rule out the possibility of the IDS driver using the GPU, I am using DEVICE INDEPENDENT BITMAP (DIB) Mode, which does not use GPU processing or memory, instead uses the CPU and computer memory. Since I am allocating the memory and copying the frame from the camera buffer myself, I believe that it is not using GPU.
I will take a look into the plugins. Currently we have compressed and theora subtopics being published. I will take a look into them and maybe disabling them to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I could solve my issue. I executed the following steps:

1. First, I disabled all the image transport plugins based on this [answer command](https://answers.ros.org/question/255970/how-to-deactivate-image_transport-plugins/);
   This do not changed GPU memory consumption, which eliminates image transport as a culprit.
2. I was loading the camera parameters from a parameter file,  and it seems that this parameter file was causing the camera driver to use GPU, and when the driver loads the parameter file it overwrites all the previous camera parameters. Since I was setting DIB mode before loading parameters it was being overwritten, so I just forced the DIB mode after my driver loads the parameter file and the GPU memory consumption problem is gone.

---

Originally posted by [gabrielPeixoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/54213/gabrielpeixoto/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-04**:
Thanks for reporting back.

So it was the camera after all.

**Comment by [gabrielPeixoto](https://answers.ros.org/users/54213/gabrielpeixoto/) on 2020-05-04**:
Indeed it was, other person made the configuration file, so I thought they were OK.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-04**:
Ah, assumptions ;)